# Make list from function + loop

Tags: python

Here is the whole code: I want to make an loop where I skip one more row from the input file each time.

import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    import quandl
    import scipy.optimize as sco
    from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
    register_matplotlib_converters()

```
mylist=[]

for i in range(0,4):
    table = pd.read_excel(r"Priser.xlsx",skiprows=i,usecols="b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p")
    table1 = np.array(table.values)

    returns = np.log(table) - np.log(table.shift(1))
    mean_returns = returns.mean()
    cov_matrix = returns.cov()
    num_portfolios = 1
    risk_free_rate = 0.0178

    def portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
        returns = np.sum(mean_returns*weights ) *252
        std = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
        return std, returns

    def random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
        results = np.zeros((3,num_portfolios))
        weights_record = []
        for i in range(num_portfolios):
            weights = np.random.random(15)
            weights /= np.sum(weights)
            weights_record.append(weights)
            portfolio_std_dev, portfolio_return = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
            results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
            results[1,i] = portfolio_return
            results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
        return results, weights_record


    def neg_sharpe_ratio(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
        p_var, p_ret = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        return -(p_ret - risk_free_rate) / p_var

    def max_sharpe_ratio(mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
        num_assets = len(mean_returns)
        args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)
        constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
        bound = (0.0,1.0)
        bounds = tuple(bound for asset in range(num_assets))
        result = sco.minimize(neg_sharpe_ratio, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args,
                            method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
        return result

    def portfolio_volatility(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
        return portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)[0]

    def min_variance(mean_returns, cov_matrix):
        num_assets = len(mean_returns)
        args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
        bound = (0.0,0.15)
        bounds = tuple(bound for asset in range(num_assets))

        result = sco.minimize(portfolio_volatility, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args,
                            method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)

        return result

    def efficient_return(mean_returns, cov_matrix, target):
        num_assets = len(mean_returns)
        args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix)

        def portfolio_return(weights):
            return portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)[1]

        constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: portfolio_return(x) - target},
                    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
        bounds = tuple((0,1) for asset in range(num_assets))
        result = sco.minimize(portfolio_volatility, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
        return result


    def efficient_frontier(mean_returns, cov_matrix, returns_range):
        efficients = []
        for ret in returns_range:
            efficients.append(efficient_return(mean_returns, cov_matrix, ret))
        return efficients

    def display_calculated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate):
        results, _ = random_portfolios(num_portfolios,mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)

        max_sharpe = max_sharpe_ratio(mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)
        sdp, rp = portfolio_annualised_performance(max_sharpe['x'], mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        max_sharpe_allocation = pd.DataFrame(max_sharpe.x,index=table.columns,columns=['allocation'])
        max_sharpe_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in max_sharpe_allocation.allocation]
        max_sharpe_allocation = max_sharpe_allocation.T

        min_vol = min_variance(mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        sdp_min, rp_min = portfolio_annualised_performance(min_vol['x'], mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        min_vol_allocation = pd.DataFrame(min_vol.x,columns=['allocation'])
        min_vol_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in min_vol_allocation.allocation]
        min_vol_allocation = min_vol_allocation.T


        print (min_vol_allocation)
        mylist.append(min_vol_allocation)


        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
        plt.scatter(results[0,:],results[1,:],c=results[2,:],cmap='YlGnBu', marker='o', s=10, alpha=0.3)
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.scatter(sdp,rp,marker='*',color='r',s=500, label='Maximum Sharpe ratio')
        plt.scatter(sdp_min,rp_min,marker='*',color='g',s=500, label='Minimum volatility')

        target = np.linspace(rp_min, 0.32, 50)
        efficient_portfolios = efficient_frontier(mean_returns, cov_matrix, target)
        plt.plot([p['fun'] for p in efficient_portfolios], target, linestyle='-.', color='black', label='efficient frontier')
        plt.title('Calculated Portfolio Optimization based on Efficient Frontier')
        plt.xlabel('annualised volatility')
        plt.ylabel('annualised returns')
        plt.legend(labelspacing=0.8)




display_calculated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate)
```

this gives the following output:

```
                 0     1     2    3     4      5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12    13   14
allocation  0.0  3.51  0.15  2.4  0.59  12.58  6.04  15.0  8.55  3.63  2.55  15.0  15.0  15.0  0.0

             0     1     2    3     4      5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12    13   14
allocation  0.0  3.51  0.15  2.4  0.59  12.58  6.04  15.0  8.55  3.63  2.55  15.0  15.0  15.0  0.0

             0     1     2    3     4      5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12    13   14
allocation  0.0  3.51  0.15  2.4  0.59  12.58  6.04  15.0  8.55  3.63  2.55  15.0  15.0  15.0  0.0
```

I want to save all the values from allocation to a list when the code is running in a loop. I can't figure out how to do it with the append function.

Comment: I'm afraid you've simplified your code a bit too much. None of it makes any sense, since you've cut out all the parts that show how it goes together. What is `values`, for instance, and how does it relate to `example`? Your loop has nothing to do with the rest of the code, so it's meaningless.

Comment: This question is somewhat illegible. Please provide a *minimal* code example that explains the problem, and explain again what is it exactly that you want to achieve, regardless of code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about your problem. But are you looking for something like this?

```
empty_list = []
# However you get each element in the z()
# say you calculate each element named as 'elem'
empty_list.append(elem)
# do this for each element
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue boils down to doing stuff at the wrong times. Your current code is structured very strangely, with your function definitions in a loop (so they keep getting redefined), but only called after the loop ends:

```
my_list = []

for x in whatever():
    def foo(arg):
        my_list.append(arg)

foo(x)
```

That doesn't make much sense. The function doesn't depend on `x`, and the call  only happens with the last `x` value (and the last definition of the function, not that that part matters since every definition is the same).

You should rearrange things. Define all your functions outside the loop, and call them from within it:

```
my_list = []

def foo(arg):
    mylist.append(arg)

for x in whatever():
    foo(x)
```

This calls `foo` (which is only defined once!) for each value `x` gets. The function appends each one to `my_list` (this is very simplified, your real code would do a bunch of processing and append the results instead). Note that having the function do the appending might not be ideal. It might make more sense for the function to `return` its results, and let the calling code decide what to do with it. That design might let you use a list comprehension or the `map` function.